# Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' 11gR2 VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, oracle11gr2

I Have a Windows 7x64 machine with oracle 11gR2 client installed. I was able to run my c# apps (in ASP .Net Development Server not IIS) which connected to oracle using 'Oracle.DataAccess' until i had to reinstall my VS. Now i get a error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I tried reinstalling oracle and VS again but still have the problem. When i run gacutil it says

> The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
>     Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f4
>   29c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64

fuslow gives the following output

> Assembly Binder Log Entry  (30/11/2012 @ 12:49:44 PM)
>   The operation was successful.
>   Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.
>   Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
>   Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\9.0\WebDev.WebServer.exe
>   --- A detailed error log follows.
>   Pre-bind state information 
>   LOG: User = KANISHKA\Administrator
>   LOG: DisplayName = Oracle.DataAccess
>    (Partial)
>   LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/Visual Studio Projects/CSharp Projects/Web/eReconciliation Statements/01 - Trunk/eReconciliationStatements/
>   LOG: Initial PrivatePath = D:\Visual Studio Projects\CSharp Projects\Web\eReconciliation Statements\01 - Trunk\eReconciliationStatements\bin
>   LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a5cf2b76
>   LOG: Cache Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a5cf2b76
>   LOG: AppName = acd2b7a
>   Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>
> LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
>   LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\Visual Studio Projects\CSharp Projects\Web\eReconciliation Statements\01 - Trunk\eReconciliationStatements\web.config
>   LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/a5cf2b76/acd2b7a/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/a5cf2b76/acd2b7a/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Visual Studio Projects/CSharp Projects/Web/eReconciliation Statements/01 - Trunk/eReconciliationStatements/bin/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
>   LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: D:\Visual Studio Projects\CSharp Projects\Web\eReconciliation Statements\01 - Trunk\eReconciliationStatements\bin\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
>   LOG: Entering download cache setup phase.
>   LOG: Assembly Name is: Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
>   LOG: A partially-specified assembly bind succeeded from the application directory. Need to re-apply policy.
>   LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\Visual Studio Projects\CSharp Projects\Web\eReconciliation Statements\01 - Trunk\eReconciliationStatements\web.config
>   LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
>   LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
>   WRN: A duplicate assembly was found while copying the assembly item to the cache.
>   LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a5cf2b76\acd2b7a\assembly\dl3\037e6e93\00d336f9_73c1ca01\Oracle.DataAccess.dll.
>   LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.

It says GAC Lookup was unsuccessful. Could any one pls help me on this issue. I have tried making the project run as x64 too.

Comment: I found out that only web apps are having this problem.  I tried running a console and windows forms app which works fine.  I did allow permission for everyone to the oracle folder too but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling 11gR2 64 bit client and installing the 11gR2 32 bit client resolved the issue.